# How to fix column order after pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pivot-table

I have the following DataFrame where the `bit` column is in ascending order:

```
calc1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'byte': ['D0']*2 + ['D1']*2,
    'bit' : [f'bit_{i}' for i in range(7, 11)],
    'count': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    })

  byte     bit count
0   D0   bit_7     a
1   D0   bit_8     b
2   D1   bit_9     c
3   D1  bit_10     d
```

BUT after using `pivot_table`, the `bit_10` comes before the `bit_9`:

```
calc1.pivot_table(index=calc1.index, columns=['byte', 'bit'], values='count', aggfunc=lambda x:' '.join(x))

byte    D0           D1
bit  bit_7 bit_8 bit_10 bit_9
0        a   NaN    NaN   NaN
1      NaN     b    NaN   NaN
2      NaN   NaN    NaN     c
3      NaN   NaN      d   NaN
```

While I understand why it does that, I would like to know how to fix this. I want those subcolumns to go from 1 to … in the correct order.

Comment: Side note, you probably want `index=calc1.groupby('bit').cumcount()` to avoid the nans, i.e.: `calc1.pivot_table(index=calc1.groupby('bit').cumcount(), columns=['byte', 'bit'], values='count', aggfunc=lambda x:' '.join(x))`

Comment: Maybe add `sort=False` to `.pivot_table` ?

Comment: Another way to fix it is using:
`'bit' : [f'bit_{i:02}' for i in range(7, 11)]`

This creates leading zeroes in the `bit_{i}` so `bit_09` comes before `bit_10`